# Duplicate columns in a double left join - bigquery sql

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm working with three tables that need to be joined. The tables are 'default', 'program' and 'transaction'.  Transaction and program need to be joined and then that needs to be joined to default. I keep getting this error:

'Duplicate column names in the result are not supported when a destination table is present. Found duplicate(s): url, id, idNetwork, type, updated'.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```html
with renamed_b as (
    select *, url as b_url, id as b_id, idNetwork as b_idNetwork, type as b_type, updated as b_updated from `{{ extract.program.sql_source }}`
), renamed_a as (
    select *, url as a_url from `{{ extract.default.sql_source }}`
) 
select * from renamed_a a
  left join renamed_b b
    on a.commission_transaction_id = b.id
  left join `{{ extract.transaction.sql_source }}` d
    on d.idProgram = b.id
```

id, idNetwork, type, and updated don't appear in the default table and I've renamed the columns in the program table, so I'm really unclear as to where the duplicate columns are coming from.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if there's more information that would be helpful to include(:

Comment: What does the following represent? `{{ extract.transaction.sql_source }}` ... If this is expanded / replaced before execution, show the final SQL after expansion (of all similar expressions too).  It's also best to show the table / view definitions when the error refers to columns of tables / views.

Comment: If subqueries inside `with` clause are correct, then at least `url` and `id` is present in both the tables (renamef) because you select `*` in the first place

Comment: To exclude columns that you have renamed, you may use `select * except <cols_to_be_renamed>` in the outer subquery. [Check the syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_except)

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly select all columns you want instead of using `*`.

When you `select *, url as b_url [..]` what happens is that there will be both a `url` and and `b_url` column (meaning both your CTEs contain a column named `url`!) hence the duplicate column error.